# How can i bundle "Run configuration" that i've created

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-plugin

I've created my own Run configuration for Intellij Idea, but I cannot find any manual on how-to bundle this run configuration as new plugin.
Does anyone have simple example on that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i'm the person to answer.

For run configuration the best source of information i've found is

> Tomcat runner plugin

.
For plugin run - you need to add inside your plugin xml:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <!-- Initialises the UI when the user selects the plugin from the menu -->
        <configurationType implementation="com.something.<PluginName>ConfigurationType"/>
        <!-- Run - It reads the values written by the UI and runs maven job -->
        <programRunner implementation="com.something.<PluginName>Runner"/>
    </extensions>
```